# Having trouble Embedding a specific Vimeo Url

Tags: iframe, vimeo, embedded-resource, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I used to embed Vimeo videos with this url format:
https://vimeo.com/514607003 (only numbers). It works just fine. But some videos are in an other format and I can't embed them no matter what:
https://vimeo.com/605783608/493d2ee578

I'm getting this error on console when I try to embed it:

```
**GET https://player.vimeo.com/video/605783608 404 (Not Found)**
```

when I add the second Id of the video Url to the embedded Url, the error remains the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer appears to be to embed the video with a special query parameter `h` containing the second key:

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/605783608?h=493d2ee578
```

This is determined by looking at Vimeo's own embed code; I did not find documentation explaining why this is.